# Sci-fi short story, AI on ice planet asking to be shut down

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, spaceship

This is either a short story, or a novel (but most likely a short story. I don't remember it being long). It is about a girl (I think quite young: 10-30 yrs) living on an oceanic ice planet. On said planet there were some primitive human settlements (stone age - medieval tech level). There was a constantly ongoing famine problem - vegetation was scarce. It is notable, that the girl uses her small boat (kayak sized if I recall).

After some introduction, the girl meets a space ship traveler, who claims (I'm not sure if he tells this immediately) that he is an AI. He wants to be shut down, because after a long time (hundreds of years) the AI decided that it doesn't want to continue living. Because of internal programming, they cannot shut themselves, and they have killed all the humans (only overlooked this planet). It is very clear, that the AI is practically begging to be shut down, as it simply cannot die. If it's damaged or in a state of disrepair it is compelled to self-repair. Any suicidal movements are also blocked. It is implied that there are many more (AI's) like this. It looks like a human. Dialogue of the AI with the girl resembled a talk with the devil - the AI was tempting the girl with all kind of stuff (I'm not 100% sure about this last sentence, but I recall there were some offers).

The girl refuses to shut it down, but later on, there are some gigantic oceanic plants sprouting all around (growing from the sea bed all the way up to the surface).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you recall where?  Check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you remember any more details you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: @DavidW thanks for the grammar help. Sadly, I do not remember when I read it. I have a hunch it is somehow linked to RR Martin (maybe it was released in some short stories along with his?) but it is just a hunch that could mislead people. I will add on some small details in a second though.

Comment: Is it a novel or a short story? Your first sentence says both.

Comment: @MikeScott To be honest, I'm not sure. I will edit to clarify that.